# How to find a matching word in a string from a list of keywords?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, markdown

I have a static function that's supposed to analyze a string, look for words that match a pre-defined lsit of keywords, and add markdown formatting to each word that matches. It then returns the string with the added formatting.

However, no matter what I input, my code never finds a match inside the dictionary. I've triple-checked that every entry in the dictionary is spelt correctly, as well as the text being input into the function.

```
public static string ColorizeText(string text) 
{

    List<string> keywords = new()
    {
        "Block",
        "Vulnerable",
        "Weak"
    };

    string colorizedText = string.Empty;

    foreach (string word in text.Split(' ')) 
    {
        if (keywords.Contains(word)) 
        {
            colorizedText += $"<color=yellow>{word}</color>" + " ";
        } 
        
        else 
        {
            colorizedText += word + " ";
        }
    }

    return colorizedText;
}
```

I'm assuming the problem spot is `if` statement. No matter what variation of `Contains`, `Find`, etc. I try, it never registers that `word` is the same as any of the strings in `keywords.`

One thing to note: I did try hard-coding the string that it checks for, and that suddenly worked, but the whole point is that it's supposed to modular. Because of this, I'm assuming the issue is with the value of the `word` string doesn't match the strings defined in `keywords`, but I have no idea why that would be the case. I'm not used to doing a lot of work with strings, so maybe I'm just missing something with how they behave.

I've also tried messing around with Substrings and Regex, but once again I'm not seasoned with either so I haven't had much luck.

How do I get my `if` statement to recognize that the inputted word exists in the list?

Comment: well, one thing that comes to mind.. what if "Hello! My name is.." it wont  find hello cos its Hello! .. as the section was only broken up by spacing, quotes, and other punctuation will kill it as will casing.  Have you not just considered regex?

Comment: Hey Justin, as @BugFinder said regex is a good option when you've got pattern matching in your hand.

Comment: Please try to explain the problem, because this code seems to work, see: https://onlinegdb.com/oo9fxDQug

Comment: @BugFinder as I mentioned in the post, I'm inexperienced with regex, but it could be the solution. I'm just unsure what the correct regex would be. Can't mess around it with currently, but I'll give it a shot in a little while when I'm able to work on my code again. I'll update here too if I find a solution.

Comment: `keywords.Contains( word, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase )`

Comment: @JustinMartin https://regex101.com/ is a pretty damn good regex test and learn platform! Bottom right you get all kind of presets you can use to construct a regex, top right you get an explanation of the regex you are currently using and in the center .. well you test your regex and see what it would match and middle right you can check your match groups to see if you would extract the information you want

Answer (score -1):

I did some isolated testing and realized the error of my ways. For all of current use-cases for this function, a period always follows the word I was trying to colorize, making the "if" statement not recognize it, as it doesn't account for punctuaction. This is probably where regex will come in handy, so I'll give that a shot to make the function bullet-proof.

Thanks to those who commented, I don't know if would've had the idea to do the tests I did without seeing other people try out the function. This one has been bugging me for a few days, so I'm glad to get it fixed!

Comment: This _answer_ does not really **answer** the question  as asked. (see: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and the question "How to find a matching word"),  Because the answer if not (and will never be!) "I should try regular expression"